# Best way to join and store a char string with a wchar_t string in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

C++ newbie here.

I have 3 strings

```
const char section1[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
std::wstring section2 = L"section2";
const char section3[] = {0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89};
```

And I need to join them together with a result that looks like

{0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x73, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x6f 0x6e, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89}

So two ASCII bits with a Unicode section sandwiched in the middle.
What's the best way to join them and what's the best data type to store for outputting to file?

Comment: Does your wstring contain UTF-32 or UTF-16 data? In the latter case the serialization is trivial; in the latter it is not (although it is still pretty simple).

Comment: It is probably a good choice to choose UTF8 for the wstring. No endianess problems at least.

Comment: One would usually store UTF-8 data in the normal `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer;

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(section1); ++i)
  Buffer.push_back((unsigned char) section1[i]);

for (size_t i = 0; i < section2.size(); ++i) {
  unsigned short u = (unsigned short) section2[i];
  Buffer.push_back((unsigned char) (u >> 8));
  Buffer.push_back((unsigned char) (u & 0xFF));
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(section3); ++i)
  Buffer.push_back((unsigned char) section31[i]);
```

You can also use memcpy for section 1 and 3, and if you make assumptions about endianness for section2 as well. The above loops should be easy to read and understand though.

When done, you simply write Buffer.size() bytes starting from &Buffer[0]

Comment: There is no guarentee that wstring will be 2 bytes per element - so your code is not portable, hence wrong.

Comment: It's however guaranteed that the produced output will look like he wants it, and that it'll behave correctly for the BMP.